# htaccess redirect rule from www.domain.com/?page=news to www.domain.com/news

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

i need to redirect the URL as

www.domain.com/?page=news --> www.domain.com/news

Here my htaccess file:

```
Options -Multiviews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Force search engines to use www.domain.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# Specify search friendly URLs
RewriteRule ^http://www\.domain\.com/news/$ /http://www.domain.com/?page=news [L]
```

Please suggest me the exact rule to use in .htaccess file.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 2nd rule is not correct as you can't match domain name in `RewriteRule` pattern. That pattern only matches REQUEST_URI without domain name and query string.

Your 2nd rule should be like this:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+\?page=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# Specify search friendly URLs
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)page=[^&]+
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /?page=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

#### Reference: [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)

Comment: The given rule is not working. I need to redirect www.domain.com/?page=news --> www.domain.com/news like this. Please suggest rule for this.   www.domain.com?page=news still shows in browser.

Comment: Great anubhava.. Its working fine. and one more clarification, is any way to pass dynamic value instead of mentioning like news, aboutus, home etc., because i'm having more than 40 pages to redirect like this. Please help me..

Comment: Its not working. It seems www.domain.com?page=news in browser.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I do not know a thing about this, but I have seen a good tutorial posted by someone I am following on facebook:
http://www.9lessons.info/2013/11/htaccess-file-tutorial-and-tips.html

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your link, but its not satisfied what i'm expect. I need the rule which should redirect: www.domain.com/?page=news --> www.domain.com/news. Please suggest me.